# SqlDependency and notifications

Tags: sqldependency

I am working with MS SQL Server. I need to realize this:
When one client of db changes some record of the table, this changes must be sent to all clients that subscribed with SqlDependency. 
But event onNotificationChange from SqlDependency brings me 
OnNotificationChange(object caller,SqlNotificationEventArgs e)
caller thet in fact is object of SqlDependency class and contains
**Id = "c333b019-ff09-4d62-9584-074b009d56ba;70e64cf4-465f-4e54-937b-024432e6b2ca"**

and e that contains discribes changes in db like this:
**info: insert
source: data
type: change**
But i need to receive changed record directly. Because in my variant i need to exequte new query and then search for changes.
Many clients will be do much load to the server.

Answer (score 2):

It's called only once, hence why you need to reassign event on event call.